# Object References Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference

I have this problem of object references which is driving me crazy. Is it normal that when I get an Integer[] array from an object and modify some elements in this variable, it gets modified in the object as well without using any set method? For example below I want to modify timetable variable locally but not in the bestSoFar object. How can I do this? and what is really happening here?

```
for (IntTuple examRel: examsRel) 
{   
     int[] examsTogether = examRel.getData();
     double maxFitness = 0.0;
     Integer[] timetable = bestSoFar.getChromosome();

     for (int i=0; i < noOfTimeslots; i++)
     { 
          for (int j=0; j < examsTogether.length; j++)
          {
               timetable[examsTogether[j]] = i;
          }

          BestChromosome thisChromosome = evaluateChromosome(new BestChromosome(timetable));
          double thisFitness = thisChromosome.getFitness();

          if (thisFitness > maxFitness)
          {
              maxFitness = thisFitness;
              bestSoFar = thisChromosome;
          }
       }
    }
    return bestSoFar;
}
```

Comment: Evidently `getChromosome()` is returning a reference to the underlying storage, rather than creating a copy first.

Comment: Yes, it is normal, because you get reference to `Integer[]` array. If you need other behavior, you should consider cloning array before returning it.

Comment: A Array is a normal object. you have a reference on it and you can change its member. You must create a copy of it. You can use Arrays.copyOf (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29) for it

Comment: so I need to copy the array into another Integer[] array for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array in Java is an Object, so when you modify its elements, they change for all the references pointing to that array.
If you want a local copy, you should clone it. E.g.:

```
Integer[] origTimetable = bestSoFar.getChromosome();
Integer[] timetable = Arrays.copyOf (origTimetable, origTimeable.length);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if I have a copy of this timetable and modify that instead, the timetable in chromosome wouldnt be modified. But would this be avoided if the array was a primitive int[] ?

Comment: @Bernice no, using primitive `int`s wouldn't help - the object reference here is the array itself - your code wasn't modifying the existing elements, it was switching them with different ones. The exact same problem would occur with an array of primitive `int`s.

Comment: ok and same goes for the object of BestChromosome. where I am doing bestSoFat = thisChromosome I would be making them equal by having the same reference for both objects right?

Comment: @Bernice yup. Both variables would be pointing to the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal. The method is returning a reference to the array that is contained in your object. If you change what the array contains, the array is thus modified.

You'll have to make a defensive copy of the array before returning it.

You could avoid these copies by using a `List<Integer>` instead, and return an unmodifiable view of this list to prevent its modification. It would then be up to the caller to create a copy of the list if it needs to modify it:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
```